# gnu parallel: how to set the limit per second

Tags: gnu-parallel

I need to use parallel and set the rate limit per second, because I need to query an API that has a "5 per second" rate limit.

Do I must combine `-n5` and `--timeout 1`?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `--delay 0.2`.